# java & maven - intellij idea, cannot resolve symbol ошибка

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Я хочу импортировать `.jar` файл, но её не находит `idea`. Я указывал `.jar` в зависимостях, но ничего не работает.
[image: 1]

Скрин `External Libraries`:

[image: 2]

Зависимости проекта:

[image: 3]

Comment: Попробуйте сбросить кэш идеи File -> Invalidate Caches...

Comment: @TaranenkoAnt не помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня был неправильный импорт. надо было написать `import com.example.filesengine.*` и потом добавить модуль в `module-info`. Теперь у меня все работает.